# Program prints garbage values in weird places (C)

Tags: c

When I'm running the program, the 2nd and the 3rd values being printed are garbage values, and I don't know why. I think it should be the numbers I've entered.

[image: The output]

The code:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    int * students = NULL;
    int * size = &a;
    int * studentscount = &b;
    func1(students, size, studentscount);
    return 0;
}

#include "Source.h"

int checkAllocation(void * ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int * doubleArr(int *arr, int size)
{
    int * newArr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    checkAllocation(newArr);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
    size *= 2;
    newArr = (int*)realloc(newArr, size);
    checkAllocation(newArr);
    free(arr);
    return (newArr);
}

void func1(int *students, int *size, int *studentscount)
{
    int num;
    students = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    checkAllocation(students);
    *(studentscount) = 0;
    *(size) = 2;
    printf("Enter students, to end enter a negative number.\n");
    do
    {
        printf("Enter student number %d: ", *(studentscount)+1);
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num >= 0)
        {
            *(students + *(studentscount)) = num;
            *(studentscount) += 1;
        }
        if (*(studentscount) == (*size))
        {
            students = doubleArr(students, *(size));
            *(size) *= 2;
        }
    } while (num >= 0);
    printf("******************\nArray size: %d\nNumber of students: %d\n******************\n", *(size), *(studentscount));
    for (int i = 0; i < *(studentscount); i++)
        printf("student #%d: %d\n", i + 1, *(students + i));
    free(students);
}
```

Any suggestions to make the code print the values I entered and not the garbage values?

Comment: Read first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Also, I would recommend debugging your application before asking.

Comment: We don't know what you app is supposed to do.  There are no inputs or outputs. shown in the question.  We have no details of what debugging you have done and what you found out.   You code is full of stars.  There are no comments.  There is no design data.

Comment: On the plus side, it is at least indente and the variables etc have sane names, (mod. func1)

Comment: `realloc(newArr, size);` --> `realloc(newArr, size*sizeof(int));`

Comment: 1) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general. 2) **Always* check results for errors. 3) No [mcve] 4) Implicit declarations of functions are not allowed. Your compiler should warn, why do you ignore warnings?

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues you should probably work on, but the reason for garbage is very likely statement `realloc(newArr, size)`, which considers only the count but not the size of datatype `int`. Hence, instead of doubling the array size, you are actually decreasing it; Consequently, `realloc` might give you back a different memory block where only portions of the previous one has been taken over; or some parts of the memory you have written values to have gone invalid. Anyway, you have a good chance here to loose your entered values. So - as pointed out by bluepixy, statement `realloc(newArr, size*sizeof(int))` should solve the main problem.

Note further that statement `realloc`, when allocating memory at a different place, takes over the content of the former memory block and (in this case) frees the former block (cf. [cppreference of `realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)). So there is no need to transfer the data manually, there is particularly no need to first `malloc` and then `realloc`, and there is consequently no need for a separate `free` at the end. So the code of `doubleArr` could actually look like the following.

```
int * doubleArr(int *arr, int size) {
    return realloc(arr,size*2*sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: I changed the code of 'doubleArr' and now it works, thank you very much.